# how to get the missing file sha256?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to run some script on Linux Ubuntu Precise Pangolin (12.04), x86_64 machine, and it complains that the file

```
/sbin/sha256
```

is not there.  I can setup in the script, where that file is, so I searched the whole system, and the file is not there...

What is this file, should it be present in Ubuntu by default, if not, where to get it from?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the preinstalled command `sha256sum`.  It's usually in `/usr/bin/`, but you can find its location using `which`:

```
$ which sha256sum
/usr/bin/sha256sum
```

There is also a package `hashalot` for Precise which installs the `sha256` command to `/sbin` (see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/hashalot/filelist)).  You can install it using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install hashalot
```

Comment: OK, I used sha256sum, I will try the other suggestion too.  I can see that I got the point of failure, but then there is another failure, so I am not sure if your suggestion "worked" yet.

Comment: OK I installed `hashalot`, but it installed to `/usr/sbin` not `/sbin` as I would prefer.  Is there a way to install it to `/sbin`  ?

Comment: It's just a file, so `mv /usr/sbin/sha256 /sbin`.  That being said, the better option would be to adjust the path in the script to point to `/usr/sbin`

Comment: OK, if it is just one file, yes, thank you.  I was just worried it depended on other stuff.

Comment: I am sorry Brian, it does not work.  The original sha256 command, whatever it was supposed to do, not sure, but it was supposed to output a readable string when called with a binary file as argument, and it was supposed to run, as ordinary user.  The one I installed by your instructions, outputs a binary value, and it demands root.

Comment: OK, so it looks like `/usr/bin/sha256sum` works, and the installed `sha256` has different functionality and it does not work.